# Progress Bar - Pause for 0.5 seconds on increments?

Tags: android

I have a progressbar that I want to advance for 5 seconds exactly. Im trying to go through a 'for' loop 10 times and for each run through the loop increment the progressbar by 1/10th of the bar. I have the code for incrementing the bar for 1/10th but Im now trying to create a loop that:

Increments the bar to 1/10th
waits 0.5 seconds...
Increments the bar to 2/10th
waits 0.5 seconds...
Increments the bar to 3/10th
waits 0.5 seconds...
etc.

Here is my code so far but it does not work, it advances the bar to 10/10 (full). Any ideas?

Thanks so much.

```
             for(int a = 0; a <= 10; a++){  
                 if(mp1.isPlaying()){   // my 5 second wav file

                       int newProgress = pBar1.getProgress() + (pBar1.getMax() / 10);
                        if (newProgress < 0) {
                            newProgress = 0;
                           }
                  pBar1.setProgress(newProgress);
                 // pause for 0.5 seconds here//
               }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.sleep(500);` will pause for half a second. But you'll have to do this in a thread other than the UI thread.  If you put the UI thread to sleep, all other interaction in your app will lock up until the sleep is over.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with what you're asking is that while it's easy to pause for 0.5 seconds my making a [thread sleep](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29), your entire UI is going to freeze which is bad, you shouldn't do this.

Your real problem seems to be that you want a progress bar that illustrates the time elapsed in an audio clip that you are playing.  If you are using [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), you can use `getCurrentPosition` and `getDuration` to calculate this for any size audio clip. i.e.:

```
//Calculate the current clip position as a value between 0 and 100
int progress = (int) ((float) mp1.getCurrentPosition() / mp1.getDuration() * 100);
```